# MOQ'ing method call sequence

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am mocking out a wrapper we use for some enterprise library calls. All was well in the world, my tests passed and the actual code worked!

However I then extended the functionality, and verified the tests all still passed. Bingo - they did. However they didn't in the real world because there is an expectation that

```
InitialiseDBCommand(string, commandtype)
```

will be called before

```
AddCmdParameter(string, dbtype, object)
```

So like a good boy, the first thing I want to do is write a test that exhibits this behavior and expects an exception to be thrown.

What I need is to rig up AddCmmParater to throw an exception IF InitialDBCommand has not been called with any string.

I figure I could do this with a call back, but it feels like moq'ing a method call sequence (not a method return sequence) ought to be there.

Something like

```
iDataAccessHelper.Setup(s=>s.AddCmdOutputParameter(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                  It.IsAny<DbType>(), 
                  It.IsAny<int>()))
              .When(w=>w.InitialiseDBCommand(etc etc)
              .Throws<NullReferenceException>()
```

Any pointers?

Comment: What are you actually testing ? Which method ? `AddCmdParameter` ? You should write this scenario as a unit test not a complex mock scenario.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov simply put I believe the OP wants a test which proves that InitialiseDBCommand is called before AddCmdParameter

Comment: I am testing a method called 'WriteBlob' that uses a data access layer. The data access layer contains these 2 calls, which it seems have an order dependency. I can see what our getting at - the test for this needs to be closer to the data access layer code itself.

Comment: This has been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602264/using-moq-to-verify-calls-are-made-in-the-correct-order) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765738/how-to-test-method-call-order-with-moq)

Comment: They seem to relate more to multiple calls to the same method, each returning a differing value. Support which is now within Moq.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you simply want to test if 2 methods are called in the correct order, one way to do it would be to add a counter that is incremented each time one of the methods is called and then check if it's the correct number. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609506/940072) is one answer that describes it.
Here is how I'd write it for your scenario:

```
[Test]
public void TestingCallOrder() {
    int counter = 0;
    var mockDataAccessStuff = new Mock<IDataAccessStuff>();
    mockDataAccessStuff.Setup(x => x.AddCmdParameter(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback(() => {
        Assert.AreEqual(counter, 0);
        counter++;
    });

    mockDataAccessStuff.Setup(x => x.InitialiseDbCommand(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback(() => {
        Assert.AreEqual(counter, 1);
        counter++;
    });

    // more of the same
    var myClass = new ClassThatImTesting(mockDataAccessStuff.Object);
    myClass.DoWork();

    // make sure both methods are called at least once ...
    mockDataAccessStuff.Verify(x => x.AddCmdParameter(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
    mockDataAccessStuff.Verify(x => x.InitialiseDbCommand(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
}
```

I think that's a very clean and readable way to write the test.

Comment: That is basically the route I have started going down. Thanks.

Comment: That's a neat way of doing it, but I would put an extra assert in there to check that the methods were called. At present if neither is called the test will pass and it probably shouldn't.

Comment: @AndyNichols Yep, agreed ! Added 2 extra asserts

Answer (score 3):

There is a library that extends Moq to add this functionality called [Moq Sequences](https://github.com/dwhelan/Moq-Sequences). Which from their examples looks like

```
using (Sequence.Create())
{
    mock.Setup(_ => _.Method1()).InSequence();
    mock.Setup(_ => _.Method2()).InSequence(Times.AtMostOnce());
    ...
    // Logic that triggers the above method calls should be done here.
    ...

}";
```

It asserts that Method1 is called before Method2

Comment: This sounds like what I was looking for.. why don't they incorporate it into Moq actual!